# How to get the context used in index.query() using langchain

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

I am using Langchain to extract pieces of information from a PDF document,
The aim is to determine from which page of the PDF OpenAI extracted the `context`.

But my first step is to have this `context`.

This is my code:

```py
response = self.index.query(question=req, llm=ChatOpenAI())
```

The `index` is from this function:

```py
def set_file(self, file_path):
    loader = None
    loader = PyPDFLoader(file_path)
    data = loader.load()
    self.index = VectorstoreIndexCreator(
        vectorstore_cls=DocArrayInMemorySearch
    ).from_documents(data)
```

I have read documentation but couldn't find anything.